# Get text between two words

Tags: c#, text

I need to know how i can get the the word(s) between two given words.
I unfortunately have no idea how to do this.
As example: Hello  good day.

How can i do do this?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ first? You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I'm afraid not, i couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand this problem rightly...

```
public static String GetTextBetween(String source, String leftWord, String rightWord)
        {
            return
                Regex.Match(source, String.Format(@"{0}\s(?<words>[\w\s]+)\s{1}", leftWord, rightWord),
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["words"].Value;
        }
```

Use:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetTextBetween("Hello good day", "hello", "day"));
```

Read about it on msdn: [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hs600312.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm trying to get the "NAME.COM LLC" from the following information: "Registrar: NAME.COM LLC   Whois Server" I'm using this to select the text: GetTextBetween(test, "Registrar:", "Whois"); It returns an empty string. Any help?

Comment: You should include punctuation in pattern: replace (?<words>[\w\s]+) to (?<words>[\w\s.:]+)

Comment: Two get words between two html tags (like <div> *word* </div>), it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: because [\w\s] doesn't match < and ? symbols... try [\w\s\<\>\/] or smth like that

Comment: public static String GetTextBetween(this String source, String leftWord, String rightWord)
        {
            var startIndex = source.IndexOf(leftWord, StringComparison.Ordinal) + leftWord.Length;
            var result = source.Substring(startIndex);
            var length = result.IndexOf(rightWord, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            return result.Substring(0, length);
        }

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to methods for this :

1. [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)
2. [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904308%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Just substring using the values returned by IndexOf the two words.

It's pretty simple, If you need further help - Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a regular expression and the string.Split in order to keep the regex simple:

```
Regex.Match("string here",@"(?<=firstWord).*?(?=secondWord)").Value
    .Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think Dragonfires code is better. Thanks for helping me though!

Answer (score 0):

Initially here you have a string and you want to extract the first several characters into a new string. We can use the Substring instance method with two parameters here, the first being 0 and the second being the desired length.

Program that uses Substring [C#]

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string input = "OneTwoThree";

    // Get first three characters
    string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
    Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub);
    }
}
```

Output

Substring: One

Refer [SubString](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)

Comment: I don't know the length of the word, because it's dynamic. Thanks for helping me though!