# Create regex to find a sub-string that may or may not contain white space or new line?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a large string like the one below :

> A new string with **content-start** content here **content-end**. A new string with blah
>   blah.A new string with blah blah.
>
> A new string with blah blah.
>
> A new string with **content-        start** content here **content-end.**
>
> A new string with blah blah.A new string with blah blah.
>
> A new string with **content-
>
>   start** content here **content-end**.
>
> A new string with blah blah.

I want to match `content-start` and `content-end` sub-strings in the whole string *** separately even if they have white spaces or new lines in between them anywhere*** .

Any input about such a regex expression is appreciated.

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733888/get-text-between-two-words), then post a real question with a [mcve], not just your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about that one:

```
content\s*-\s*start(.*?)content\s*-\s*end
```

\s considers **\r \n \t \v space**

Additionally you may do this as well in your c# regex:

```
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)

//Which indicates dot matches newline
// RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace ignores whitespaces in pattern
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kHuVbC/1)

Comment: will this consider new lines ?

Comment: yes \s considers \r \n \t \v space

Comment: What are the reasons behind putting up negative vote without reasoning !!!

Comment: what if a space comes between n and t or c and o ? How to consider that ?

Comment: `c\s*o\s*n\s* ....` you may apply this